# Commented-out Profile Center link removed in the Plain Text version. Marketing Cloud complains about it

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, html, profile-center

We have built some custom Content Blocks for emails for our client so that they can drag-and-drop them and build their own mails without the help of HTML. All the necessary links are provided in the footer (unsubscribe, physical address, etc). But in the code we have commented **the Profile Center URL** out (`<!-- %%profile_center_url%% -->`). The reason is that, even though this link is obligatory, but our client has their own Profile center and they do not want subscribers to go to the SFMC.

We have faced some incidents since the customer has started building the emails that they have come back with the following error: 
[image]

The way to fix it is to switch to the Plain Text version, add the profile link URL variable and then continue. But of course, we do not want to add this unnecessary step for the client.

They do not have any check or control or the Plain Text version. Is there a way to avoid this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid it completly use AMPScript Coding:

```
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%% %%Member_Busname%% %%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%% %%Member_State%% %%Member_PostalCode%% %%Member_Country%% %%profile_center_url%% %%[ endif ]%%
```

This condition (0 = 1) will never be true, therefore the ampscript will never output the values inside of the code. That is one possible way to get around it.

The other way is that you ask salesforce Support if they can check your template and change the settings of "profilecenter" being mandatory in your emails, which is disabling the can-spam validation. To achieve this you just open a support case.

Comment: It is currently only the `%%profile_center_url%%` that is raising issues. So I guess that is the variable we would like to have. But where should this code reside? In HTML code? As I said we don't even want to bother with plain text version.

Comment: You can put this code anywhere into the HTML. Mails are always interpreted in full (html, then text), so if the AMPScript is _anywhere_, it will be found when SFMC parses content. Suggestion is, bottom of all HTML templates used throughout the system.

Comment: Will this workaround prevent the automatically generated Plain Text version to stop complaining?

Comment: Yes it should. You only need to include the %%profile_center_url%% in this ampscript clause, when you use the other ones somewhere or get no warning ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can raise a request with SF team asking them to disable CAN-SPAM validation - this will allow you to leave this content out entirely in the future.

Comment: We don't want to completely disable the CAN-SPAM. But is the profile center link a part of it when we already have links to the Subscription Center where they can opt in and out of communications?